# Nginx reverse proxy to another nginx server serving static files

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx server hosting a web app which works fine when directly accessed. Its config is below

```
server {
    listen 8000 default_server;

    listen [::]:8000 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /data/www/ ;
    server_name server1.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    location /app/ {

    }    
}
```

Now i have to serve this app from another Nginx server So i setup the reverse proxy like below

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /data/www/ ;
        server_name server2.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }

        location /app/ {
                proxy_pass http://server1.com:8000/app/;
        }
```

When i access the app from server2 i am getting errors like below for example when i am accessing http://server2.com/app/css/app.css  (sorry no rep to post links)

> [error] 6601#0: *1 open() "/data/www/app/css/app.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)

and no errors in server1 logs. Why is nginx looking for static files in server2 when i have set it to reverse proxy to server1 same setup works fine in apache with

> ProxyPass /app/ http:server1:8000/app/
>
> ProxyPassReverse /app/ http:server1:8000/app/

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 4):

You generally don't need to add the path to nginx!

The path from the location gets added automatically

so this

```
location /app/ {
      proxy_pass http://server1.com:8000/app/;
}
```

should really be:

```
 location /app/ {
      proxy_pass http://server1.com:8000;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your second nginx instance that's trying to serve files locally:

```
   location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }
```

Just remove that whole thing if you want to serve using http://server2.com/app/. If you want to use http://server2.com/ instead, update the config to reflect that:

```
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

   server_name server2.com;

   location / {
          proxy_pass http://server1.com:8000/app/;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I implemented it for my download site and it works. http://onesoftwares.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the more specific `/app/` location in your proxy before/above the more generic `/` location, as nginx may be handling the location rules in a way you didn't intend.

Comment: that did not help but the config in server2 location ~* \.(css|js)$ { expires 365d; } for browser caching was causing the issue thanks for your response